# Can I change CheckBox color in LongListMultiSelector? WP8

Tags: checkbox, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I need to change the color for the LongListMultiSelector's CheckBox in Windows Phone 8, because my background is white, this is possible?

Thanks.

[image: CheckBox image]

Comment: you can change the background color to change box color and change the foreground color for text ..

Answer (score 9):

In order to do that you have to first edit the ItemContainerSyle by right clicking on the longlistselector from document outline in visual studio and then choose  Edit Additional Style -> Edit ItemContainerSyle -> Create Empty

Then you have to replace the setters for the generated template with the original setter code from codeplex.

the following setters code centers the check boxes and makes then grey:

```
<Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:LongListMultiSelectorItem">
                    <Grid MinHeight="52">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="8" x:Key="ExponentialEaseIn"/>
                            <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" x:Key="QuadraticEaseOut"/>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionEnabledStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="ClosedToExposed" 
                                                  From="Closed" To="Exposed"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.30">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="1.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="ExposedToClosed" 
                                                  From="Exposed" To="Closed"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.30">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="1.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="0.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="ExposedToOpened"
                                                  From="Exposed" To="Opened"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.30">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-58" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="24" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="86" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="1.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="0.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="InnerHintPanel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="ClosedToOpened"
                                                  From="Closed" To="Opened"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-58" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="24" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="86" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="InnerHintPanel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition x:Name="OpenedToClosed"
                                                  From="Opened" To="Closed"
                                                  GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="-58" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="86" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="24" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualStateGroup.States>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Closed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Exposed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel"
                                                         Duration="0" To="1.0"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox"
                                                         Duration="0" To="0"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter"
                                                         Duration="0" To="86"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="OuterCover">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel"
                                                         Duration="0" To="0.0"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetName="InnerHintPanel">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup.States>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" primitives:ClipToBounds.IsEnabled="True">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter">
                                    <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform TranslateX="24"/>
                                    </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </Grid>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="InnerHintPanel" Grid.Column="0" Width="24"
                                   Height="{TemplateBinding HintPanelHeight}"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   Fill="Transparent"
                                   StrokeThickness="0">
                                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform TranslateX="24"/>
                                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="InfoPresenter" Grid.Column="1" 
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        Content="{TemplateBinding ContentInfo}"
                                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentInfoTemplate}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="OuterHintPanel" Width="24"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Height="{TemplateBinding HintPanelHeight}"
                               Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                               StrokeThickness="0" Opacity="0.0"/>
                        <Grid x:Name="OuterCover" IsHitTestVisible="True"
                          Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent"/>
                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <CheckBox x:Name="SelectBox" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" BorderBrush="#FF4B4B4B" Foreground="#FF424242" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyleGrey}">
                                <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-58"/>
                                </CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </Canvas>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
```

Now the check box will appear as grey but the actual ticks inside will still be white (since they inherit from the mobile's resources).

What you can do is edit the check box style as well with the same way.
The following code will make the tick grey:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyleGrey" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase}" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Border x:Name="CheckBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="IndeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                            <Path x:Name="CheckMark" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="21" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="23" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="12,0,0,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```