# How to change the CheckBox and CheckBox tick's color in LongListMultiSelector? WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, checkbox, longlistselector

Is it possible to change the CheckBox and CheckBox tick's color in LongListMultiSelector. I've tried George Nikolaides solution but I was not able to approach what I needed. Is there any other way to do this? Please can somebody explain this in a little bit more detail? if it's possible. Thanks in advance, 
The following is George Nikolaides solution:

[Can I change CheckBox color in LongListMultiSelector? WP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786616/can-i-change-checkbox-color-in-longlistmultiselector-wp8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember to have `xmlns:toolkit` and `xmlns:toolkitPrimitives` defined like so:

```XAML
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"   
    xmlns:toolkitPrimitives="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Primitives;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit">
```

Then copy this entire mess to the `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>`

```
<Style x:Key="PhoneButtonBase" TargetType="ButtonBase">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,10,6"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBase}" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" BasedOn="{StaticResource PhoneRadioButtonCheckBoxBase}" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Grid Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxPressedBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneButtonBasePressedForegroundBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="IndeterminateMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="32"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Border x:Name="CheckBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="32"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="IndeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxCheckBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                            <Path x:Name="CheckMark" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="21" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="23"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="12,0,0,0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="LongListMultiSelectorItemListStyle" TargetType="toolkit:LongListMultiSelectorItem">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:LongListMultiSelectorItem">
                <Grid MinHeight="52">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseIn" Exponent="8" x:Key="ExponentialEaseIn"/>
                        <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseOut" x:Key="QuadraticEaseOut"/>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionEnabledStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="ClosedToExposed" 
                                    From="Closed" To="Exposed"
                                    GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.30">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="1.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="ExposedToClosed" 
                                    From="Exposed" To="Closed"
                                    GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.30">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="1.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="0.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="ExposedToOpened"
                                    From="Exposed" To="Opened"
                                    GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.30">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-58" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="24" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="86" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="1.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="0.0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource QuadraticEaseOut}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="InnerHintPanel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="ClosedToOpened"
                                    From="Closed" To="Opened"
                                    GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="-58" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="24" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="86" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="InnerHintPanel">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                                <VisualTransition x:Name="OpenedToClosed"
                                    From="Opened" To="Closed"
                                    GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="0" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="-58" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="86" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="24" EasingFunction="{StaticResource ExponentialEaseIn}"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Closed"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Exposed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel"
                                        Duration="0" To="1.0"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Opened">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox"
                                        Duration="0" To="0"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Presenter"
                                        Duration="0" To="86"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="SelectBox">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="OuterCover">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel"
                                        Duration="0" To="0.0"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="OuterHintPanel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="InnerHintPanel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" toolkitPrimitives:ClipToBounds.IsEnabled="True">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <CompositeTransform TranslateX="24"/>
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="InnerHintPanel" Grid.Column="0" Width="24"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding HintPanelHeight}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Fill="Transparent"
                            StrokeThickness="0">
                            <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform TranslateX="24"/>
                            </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                        </Rectangle>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="InfoPresenter" Grid.Column="1" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Top"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding ContentInfo}"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentInfoTemplate}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="OuterHintPanel" Width="24"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Height="{TemplateBinding HintPanelHeight}"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        StrokeThickness="0" Opacity="0.0"/>
                    <Grid x:Name="OuterCover" IsHitTestVisible="True"
                        Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <CheckBox x:Name="SelectBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="12,-20,5,0" Visibility="Collapsed"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource CheckBoxStyle1}" Foreground="Red" BorderBrush="#FF00FF46">
                            <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                                <CompositeTransform TranslateX="-58"/>
                            </CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </Canvas>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

---

```
<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LongListMultiSelectorItemListStyle}">
```

Select the CheckBox in the style and change the BorderBrush Color and Foreground Color to achieve what you want.  I tied the Foreground Color to the Check Mark thingy.

---

[image]

Comment: I would add more detail to the solution. But I ran up to the 30,000 char limit.  I hopes this helps you.  Remember to select the CheckBox in the style and change the brushes to get your desired results.