# ListView change color of multiple checkbox

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

How can I change the color of the `listview` checkbox when `selectionmode` is `Multiple`.

The checkbox is always a white color.

On black background checkbox is white color. On white background i need set checkbox color on black.

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxSJD.png

Comment: We need more details to know how to answer your question :
A screen capture of your interface and/or a small code example would be good.
If you don't provide them, we will take more time helping you, or won't even be able to help

Comment: It was pretty difficult in WP8.0, see my answer here.  You can probably convert it with minimal difficulty to make it work for WP8.1.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560039/how-to-change-the-checkbox-and-checkbox-ticks-color-in-longlistmultiselector-w/26560870#26560870

Comment: Maybe there is a solution easier?